# Wired error when using for loop Object in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I just got a weird error when I try to loop through the object and return the children component.

Here is the code I trying to do:

```
 if(itemData){
      var listItem;
      for (var key in itemData) {
       let data = itemData[key]

        listItem = [...listItem, (<ListItem itemData= {data} />)];
       }
     console.log(listItem, 'list item');
    }
```

It says:

```
TypeError: Invalid attempt to spread non-iterable instance
 for (var key in itemData) {
  31 |    let data = itemData[key]
  32 |     
> 33 |     listItem = [...listItem, (<ListItem itemData= {data} />)];
     | ^  34 |    }
  35 |  console.log(listItem, 'list item');
  36 | }
```

Ps: itemData just a normal object with some field inside.
Can someone have a look on my code and tell me what is wrong? 
Is there any difference between loop through array and object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You only declared `var listItem;`, and did not assign anything to it, so its value at the first iteration was `undefined`.

To fix it, change your declaration to:

`var listItem = [];`